How to solve a Riccati differential equation that involves a linear 1rst degree one with an integral that can't be calculated with ordinary methods
I'm trying to solve the following Riccati differential equation:
$$y'+xy^2-x^3y-2x=0$$
given that $y_p=x^2$.
I transform it into a Bernoulli differential equation. And I get:
$$Y'+x^3Y+xY^2=0$$
Then transform it again into a first degree linear one:
$$u'-x^3u=x$$
By setting $u(x)=g(x)U(x)$ and finding that $g(x)=e^{x^4/4}$ I then must solve the integral to find $U(x)$ which is $$\int \frac{x}{e^{x^4/4}} dx$$ Which can't be solved with elementary methods and I haven't learned to apply numerical approximation/series expansion.
Is there any other method to approach the initial Riccati or to solve the linear first degree differential equation?
Τhanks in advance!

The integral evaluates to
$$
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}, \mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)}{2}
$$

To get more variety in exercises, advanced ODE problems also count as solved if you have reduced ODE integration to quadrature, the is, simple integrals. Sometimes there are obvious primitive functions, but more often not.

If tour problem is to compute
$$U(x)=\int x\,e^{-\frac{x^4}{4}} \,dx$$ let $x^4=4t^2$ to face
$$\int e^{-t^2}\,dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  \text{erf}(t)$$ Back to $x$
$$U(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}   \text{erf}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$
